# Printing conditional statements in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

1. This is normal text.Hi, I need to solve a problem with a list of dictionaries and conditional statements, however my code gives me no output - but no error message either. This is the problem:

Define a variable named ‘dataset’ that contains the following information:

```
Artist  Track   Plays
Dire Straits    Sultans of Swing    65
Pink Floyd  Comfortably Numb    23
The Smiths  Cemetery Gates  15
Nick Cave & The Bad Seeds   The Ship Song   36
Dire Straits    Brothers in Arms    20
```

Print the artist and track (title) of songs with less than 25 plays. Each artist and track combination is printed on a separate line.

Print all track titles of songs by The Smiths and Pink Floyd. Printing just the titles is ok, each title is printed on a separate line.

Print the total number of plays. This is the total number of plays of all 5 songs.

My code so far is this:

`enter code here`

```
  dataset = [
  {'Artist':'Dire Straits','Track':'Sultans of Swing','Plays':65},
  {'Artist':'Pink Floyd','Track':'Comfortably Numb','Plays':23},
  {'Artist':'The Smiths','Track':'Cemetry Gates','Plays':15},
  {'Artist':'Nick Cave & The Bad Seeds','Track':'The Ship Song','Plays':36},
  {'Artist':'Dire Straits','Track':'Brothers in Arms','Plays':20},
```

]

```
for x in dataset:
  if 'Plays' in dataset > 25:
    print (dataset['Artist','Track'])
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code, instead of asking if there is a 'Plays' property on dataset, you should access the x variable you declared on the iteration.

Try this, it should work:

```
for item in dataset:
    if item['Plays'] < 25:
        print(f"Artist: {item['Artist']} \n Track: {item['Track']}")
```